# Bamboo build fails because webpack donesn't find node_modules

Tags: npm, webpack, environment-variables, bamboo, npm-scripts

I have configured my project on angular 1.7 with webpack. In local when I run the task npm run build (launchin webpack) everything goes correctly.

But I have a plan for my CI bamboo and when a run the NPM task with npm run build I got a message, which said:

```
Error: Cannot find module './yargs'
```

I have the intuition that webpack is not able to reach the node_modules or is not in current directory.

But node_modules is installed and yargs is there after making the npm install task before.

if I run a script before the npm run build with just "ls -l" command I get:

```
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
src
webpack.config.js
```

So the folder is there.

Any idea where I can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the issue. In the Source code checkout configuration the "Force clean build" has been checked and now the build succed.

I'm not sure why, but there must have been a conflict with a previous node_modules.

Answer (score 0):

The spelling of the file that you're referring is case-sensitive when building via bamboo

building locally wouldn't give you any error nor warnings in the console.

I encountered this issue with a local file (not a node_module)... Hoping this would help someone in the future;